# c Project to an installation file (Eclipse?)

Tags: c, eclipse, installation

I wrote a c program (Connect Four), and I want to be able to send an installation file so that after the installation people would have a .exe program that runs the game.
currently, for running the game I do (cmd commands inside the game's folder)

```
make SPGameTest
```

and then `SPGameTest`

of course that sending the .exe file doesn't work for some computers..
how can I make the installation file?

can it be done using the eclipse? Thanks a lot.

Comment: By *sending it* you mean by email? Usually, if sending `exe` didn't work, sending an installer program won't work too. You don't need an installer for a simple program.

Comment: Not by email, by uploading it to a file host service.
sending the .exe file doesn't work with some computers, but if I send them the project, and make it in their environment it works (which make sense: the -o process will be different on different computers, no?)

Comment: Well, of course, if you compile it under Windows, it will work only under Windows. Same for any other OS. So if you want to send your source files and let them compile them themselves - you can use Github for that. Installer is not the way since it contains the compilation product, not the source code.